# grub "error: command failed" after 20.04.03 kernel upgrade

Tags: grub2, 20.04

I'm running 20.04.03.  I upgraded to linux-image-5.11.0-27-generic.
Before rebooting I said "apt autoremove".  Now when I power on my machine it does not boot.  I get the grub menu screen with the default being "Ubuntu".  After a timeout it says "error: command failed" 5 times and then
"error: you need to load the kernel first".

If I push ESC, I get a grub> prompt.  If I now type exit, it goes back to the menu screen and this time it boots correctly.

I tried grub-install, but it did not help.
I tried making a new grub.cfg with grub-mkconfig, but it was no different from what I had.

Here is my grub.cfg:

```
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  set have_grubenv=true
  load_env
fi
if [ "${initrdfail}" = 2 ]; then
   set initrdfail=
elif [ "${initrdfail}" = 1 ]; then
   set next_entry="${prev_entry}"
   set prev_entry=
   save_env prev_entry
   if [ "${next_entry}" ]; then
      set initrdfail=2
   fi
fi
if [ "${next_entry}" ] ; then
   set default="${next_entry}"
   set next_entry=
   save_env next_entry
   set boot_once=true
else
   set default="0"
fi

if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
  menuentry_id_option="--id"
else
  menuentry_id_option=""
fi

export menuentry_id_option

if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}
function initrdfail {
    if [ -n "${have_grubenv}" ]; then if [ -n "${partuuid}" ]; then
      if [ -z "${initrdfail}" ]; then
        set initrdfail=1
        if [ -n "${boot_once}" ]; then
          set prev_entry="${default}"
          save_env prev_entry
        fi
      fi
      save_env initrdfail
    fi; fi
}
function recordfail {
  set recordfail=1
  if [ -n "${have_grubenv}" ]; then if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then save_env recordfail; fi; fi
}
function load_video {
  if [ x$feature_all_video_module = xy ]; then
    insmod all_video
  else
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod ieee1275_fb
    insmod vbe
    insmod vga
    insmod video_bochs
    insmod video_cirrus
  fi
}

if [ x$feature_default_font_path = xy ] ; then
   font=unicode
else
insmod part_gpt
insmod ext2
set root='hd0,gpt7'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt7 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt7 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt7  df44052a-ea84-4ed1-8682-c77db1981c09
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root df44052a-ea84-4ed1-8682-c77db1981c09
fi
    font="/usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2"
fi

if loadfont $font ; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  set locale_dir=$prefix/locale
  set lang=en_US
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_output gfxterm
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ] ; then
  set timeout=30
else
  if [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then
    set timeout_style=hidden
    set timeout=10
  # Fallback hidden-timeout code in case the timeout_style feature is
  # unavailable.
  elif sleep --interruptible 10 ; then
    set timeout=0
  fi
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
function gfxmode {
    set gfxpayload="${1}"
    if [ "${1}" = "keep" ]; then
        set vt_handoff=vt.handoff=7
    else
        set vt_handoff=
    fi
}
if [ "${recordfail}" != 1 ]; then
  if [ -e ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt ]; then
    if hwmatch ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt 3; then
      if [ ${match} = 0 ]; then
        set linux_gfx_mode=keep
      else
        set linux_gfx_mode=text
      fi
    else
      set linux_gfx_mode=text
    fi
  else
    set linux_gfx_mode=keep
  fi
else
  set linux_gfx_mode=text
fi
export linux_gfx_mode
menuentry 'Ubuntu' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-df44052a-ea84-4ed1-8682-c77db1981c09' {
    recordfail
    load_video
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,gpt7'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt7 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt7 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt7  df44052a-ea84-4ed1-8682-c77db1981c09
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root df44052a-ea84-4ed1-8682-c77db1981c09
    fi
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.11.0-27-generic root=UUID=df44052a-ea84-4ed1-8682-c77db1981c09 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-27-generic
}
submenu 'Advanced options for Ubuntu' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-df44052a-ea84-4ed1-8682-c77db1981c09' {
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 5.11.0-27-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.11.0-27-generic-advanced-df44052a-ea84-4ed1-8682-c77db1981c09' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt7'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt7 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt7 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt7  df44052a-ea84-4ed1-8682-c77db1981c09
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root df44052a-ea84-4ed1-8682-c77db1981c09
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 5.11.0-27-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.11.0-27-generic root=UUID=df44052a-ea84-4ed1-8682-c77db1981c09 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-27-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 5.11.0-27-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.11.0-27-generic-recovery-df44052a-ea84-4ed1-8682-c77db1981c09' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt7'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt7 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt7 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt7  df44052a-ea84-4ed1-8682-c77db1981c09
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root df44052a-ea84-4ed1-8682-c77db1981c09
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 5.11.0-27-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.11.0-27-generic root=UUID=df44052a-ea84-4ed1-8682-c77db1981c09 ro recovery nomodeset dis_ucode_ldr 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-27-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 5.11.0-25-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.11.0-25-generic-advanced-df44052a-ea84-4ed1-8682-c77db1981c09' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt7'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt7 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt7 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt7  df44052a-ea84-4ed1-8682-c77db1981c09
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root df44052a-ea84-4ed1-8682-c77db1981c09
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 5.11.0-25-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.11.0-25-generic root=UUID=df44052a-ea84-4ed1-8682-c77db1981c09 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-25-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 5.11.0-25-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.11.0-25-generic-recovery-df44052a-ea84-4ed1-8682-c77db1981c09' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt7'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt7 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt7 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt7  df44052a-ea84-4ed1-8682-c77db1981c09
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root df44052a-ea84-4ed1-8682-c77db1981c09
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 5.11.0-25-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.11.0-25-generic root=UUID=df44052a-ea84-4ed1-8682-c77db1981c09 ro recovery nomodeset dis_ucode_ldr 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-25-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 5.8.0-55-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.8.0-55-generic-advanced-df44052a-ea84-4ed1-8682-c77db1981c09' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt7'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt7 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt7 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt7  df44052a-ea84-4ed1-8682-c77db1981c09
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root df44052a-ea84-4ed1-8682-c77db1981c09
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 5.8.0-55-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.8.0-55-generic root=UUID=df44052a-ea84-4ed1-8682-c77db1981c09 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-5.8.0-55-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 5.8.0-55-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.8.0-55-generic-recovery-df44052a-ea84-4ed1-8682-c77db1981c09' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt7'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt7 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt7 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt7  df44052a-ea84-4ed1-8682-c77db1981c09
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root df44052a-ea84-4ed1-8682-c77db1981c09
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 5.8.0-55-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.8.0-55-generic root=UUID=df44052a-ea84-4ed1-8682-c77db1981c09 ro recovery nomodeset dis_ucode_ldr 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-5.8.0-55-generic
    }
}

### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux_zfs ###
### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux_zfs ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###
### END /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
menuentry 'Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/sda1)' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-efi-744C-6FD3' {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod fat
    set root='hd0,gpt1'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt1 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt1  744C-6FD3
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 744C-6FD3
    fi
    chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
}
set timeout_style=menu
if [ "${timeout}" = 0 ]; then
  set timeout=10
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###
menuentry 'UEFI Firmware Settings' $menuentry_id_option 'uefi-firmware' {
    fwsetup
}
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  ${config_directory}/custom.cfg ]; then
  source ${config_directory}/custom.cfg
elif [ -z "${config_directory}" -a -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg;
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
```

Here is lsblk | grep -v loop:

```
sda      8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   250M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2   8:2    0   128M  0 part 
├─sda3   8:3    0  93.3G  0 part 
├─sda4   8:4    0   990M  0 part 
├─sda5   8:5    0  14.7G  0 part 
├─sda6   8:6    0   1.7G  0 part 
└─sda7   8:7    0 820.5G  0 part /
```

and here is /dev/disk/by-partuuid/:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Aug 22 16:21 1cb28ae7-e24e-4b8b-be07-8ac6eeab32e9 -> ../../sda5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Aug 22 16:21 31b6e96f-789c-4ab6-875d-e344a2bf799b -> ../../sda2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Aug 22 16:21 44e8e646-5e5e-4ba5-9ca9-4d69413c10a2 -> ../../sda7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Aug 22 16:21 458fe370-0dda-49d2-a7b0-60524c58b7b7 -> ../../sda6
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Aug 22 16:21 9105e79c-abd3-463b-953e-590f1aa4273e -> ../../sda4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Aug 22 16:21 97f90ab9-dfa8-4cd6-858b-bca666bce453 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Aug 22 16:21 fcadf246-a9f2-4fbb-a85c-a85b4e3e9f67 -> ../../sda3
```

Comment: Hi. Did you try update-grub? I mean: sudo update-grub

Comment: Yes.  That is, I did the same thing by hand using grub-mkconfig.

Comment: Do you have any other device marked as bootable or SD card conected?

Comment: I have one built-in hard disk and no SD storage devices.  The hard disk is dual boot.

Comment: The first command in the "Ubuntu" section of the grub.cfg (see above) is recordfail.  Indeed if I just type this command to the grub> prompt it gives "command failed".  This command is apparently defined earlier in the grub.cfg, so I don't know what is wrong.

Comment: Lets try something different. two things: Can you install grub-customizer? Also edit /etc/default/grub and change GRUB_DEFAULT="saved" and GRUB_TIMEOUT="10".  Then update-grub. Grub-customizer gives you a gui option to do the changes.

Comment: Also, please provide the output of: "lsblk | grep -v loop" and "ls -l /dev/disk/by-partuuid/". Thank you.

Comment: I installed grub-customizer, which seems useful, but I don't know what you want me to do with it.  The timeout is already in /etc/default/grub.  I could change the default entry, but I don't think this matters.  I can let it default, I can select "Ubuntu" or I can select something else and the "error: command failed" behavior is always the same.

Comment: if you look at the grub.cfg file the "set root line" it is not pointing to gpt7 uuid. in grub-customizer change the option to last booted. save and reboot twice.

Comment: I must have fixed this somehow in August 2021 and neglected to write what I did.  I don't remember booting from USB as the answer suggests, but it's possible I did.  In any case, it recurred in December 2022.  This time I just said "sudo grub-install /dev/sda", and then it booted normally.

Answer (score 0):

Hope your sda7 is installation partition and sda1 is efi.
boot a live cd/pendrive
open terminal and enter these commands ***line by line.**

```
sudo mount /dev/sda7 /mnt
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot/efi
sudo rm -r /mnt/boot/efi/*
for i in /dev /dev/pts /proc /sys; do sudo mount -B $i /mnt$i; done
sudo chroot /mnt
grub-install /dev/sda
update-grub
exit
reboot
```